# Invert colors one only one monitor

Tags: windows-7, multi-monitor

I'm looking for a program for Microsoft Windows 7 that can invert color one only one monitor.

https://0.x2a.yt/other/private/NegativeScreen-custom-multi-monitor.exe ([mirror](https://archive.org/details/negative-screen)) from https://github.com/mlaily/NegativeScreen/issues/2 works quite well but has the following issues:

- [NegativeScreen makes Point N Click flicker](https://superuser.com/q/1553920/116475) if Point N Click is in one of the monitors being color inverted.
- NegativeScreen makes the mouse cursor flicker, regardless of the mouse cursor location.
- NegativeScreen takes a lot of CPU when Aero is disabled.

---

- Operating system: Microsoft Windows 7 (with Aero not required).
- License: any
- Price: any

---

Related questions:

- Linux

  - [debian/ubuntu - invert all colours in desktop session (colors)](https://superuser.com/q/570666/116475)
  - [invert colors on X (or xfce4)](https://superuser.com/q/208746/116475)
- - [Program similar to xcalib to invert desktop colors on Linux Mint](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/89959/16704)
- macOS:

  - [How can I invert colors on ONE screen in Mac OS X?](https://superuser.com/q/176500/116475)
  - [How can I invert the colors of one window on macOS? (and not the entire monitor)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/392136/20338)
- Microsoft Windows:

  - [Invert display colors on Microsoft Windows](https://superuser.com/q/358316/116475)
  - [Win7: Invert Colors Of One Specific Window](https://superuser.com/q/657653/116475)

---

I have crossposted the question at:

- [Quora](https://qr.ae/pNySwH)
- [Reddit](https://redd.it/gqgtt9)

Comment: Do you have OneNote running? OneNote registers the Win+Alt+N hotkey (try pressing it, a OneNote quick note will open) which makes the multi monitor tool crash. Close the OneNote tool and multi monitor worked for me.

Comment: This icon: https://i.stack.imgur.com/39dbr.png

Comment: I think you can use Ultramon -  https://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/

Comment: @David Turns out I use Ultramon for some other features already :) where's the option to invert the colors?

Comment: @ThomasWeller Thanks good catch that was indeed the issue! could you please add it as an answer in [NegativeScreen's custom multi-monitor version crashing on Windows 7](https://superuser.com/q/1553010/116475)? (if no time, lmk I can do) This way we'll log the issue. Thanks!